# Laptop Booting takes long time and File transfer takes hours

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, file-transfer

I have an SSD installed for booting my Windows 10 and an additional HDD of 1 TB for storage in my laptop some days ago my laptop took a long time to boot it always asks to run `chkdsk`.

Folders take a long time to open, and transferring some files which are less than a GB takes hours. Disk usage is 100%

I have tried all the suggested methods online like stopping sysmain, Windows search service, and rebuilding index but nothing works. I suspect my HDD is failing(not sure just a suspicion).

What can I do to resolve this?

**Edit:-**

[image]

[image]

Comment: The answer to this is dependant on the time since your last backup.

Comment: @Tetsujin backup was done a long time back, I have some files in HDD small in size that I need other 95% files I don't need

Comment: Copy off any new data since last backup, or run an incremental backup again before going any further. Have you run SMART tests? How full is the drive?

Comment: If you suspect your HDD is failing (which could indeed result in a severe slowdown), check the SMART report. You can access the SMART report with the CrystalDiskInfo utility (free software)

Comment: @Tetsujin I ran the SMART tests it shows OK for all the drives. anyway to backup a few GB of files?

Comment: @PierU I ran the SMART tests it shows OK for all the drives, is there anyway to save the files in mentioned drive?

Comment: What means "OK" ? Please post the entire SMART report (with individual attributes...), not just the status.

Comment: @PierU please Check Edit I have added the screenshots.

Comment: Not perfect (there are some problems on this drive), but not bad enough to explain the slowdown... @Tetsujin asked: "How full is your drive?"

Comment: What if you disconnect HDD and just run on SSD? How is the speed and performance? There are some pending sectors on HDD, a low level format (data destructive) might recover the same if they are soft issues and health may get restored again.

Comment: @Tetsujin it is only 2% full i.e just 18 GB.

Comment: @patkim when I disconnect HDD and run on SSD it runs normal file transfer is also normal. I need a few GB of data and cannot format it any solution?

Comment: Try copying the 18GB of files present on the drive to the SSD (or to an external drive) . If it takes “forever” then the drive is likely dying: some sectors are unreadable (the pending ones in the report) and the drive makes multiples attempts on each of them. A format (with a full erase, i.e. writing zeros everywhere) would temporarily revive the drive by forcing reallocating the sectors, but I recommend not using it anymore.  Keep it aside as is, and try recover individual files if you can.

Comment: @PierU yes it takes forever to copy I tried that. The only option that remains to copy individual files? I am trying Xcopy it is working but taking a long time, 1 folder has many small-size files.

Comment: Not all files will be affected by the dead sectors, so most of them should be readable and could be copied (unless there are dead sectors in the file allocation table itself... in this case even copying individual files may be impossible). Whatever the tool you use to copy, as long as you are attempting a global copy the tool will encounter some dead sectors at some point and will hang.

Comment: Some tricks can help "reviving" a HDD for a one-shot backup... The "freeze trick" is one of them: you put the HDD in a waterproof plastic bag, seal the bag, and put it a few hours in the freezer. Then you get it off the freezer and before it warms up you backup the content. Disclaimer 1: this trick can also damage the drive, so use it at your own risk, and only once you don't see any other solution; Disclaimer 2: this trick is reputed no longer working with modern drives (however I could successfully use it a few years ago on a not that old drive).

Comment: With an internal 2.5" drive, the best way to use the "freezer trick" is to buy a USB-SATA cable, put the HDD in the freeze with the cable and seal the bag around the cable. After getting the drive off the freezer you directly plug it onto a USB port without removing the bag (to avoid condensation on the drive). And Disclaimer 3: the trick can work... or not.

Comment: Also try Windows built-in Robocopy.exe command line to copy with /R:1 /W:1 switches. This will retry only once and ignore that particular file if it fails to copy. Not too sure but give it a try.

Comment: you may also give a try to the linux `ddrescue` utility: https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/